# What is the meaning of "conceive" in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

This is the context:

> Well, that’s very odd. I’m in a minority because for some reason I’m one of those people who
>   never got myself completely fascinated by this question. And in part this is because I
>   never could imagine what an answer to that question would be. I find it difficult to **conceive** of a question
>   without having some idea of the structure of an acceptable answer. If there is a structure, I don’t know
>   about it.
>
> source: The enigma of human consciousness.New York Academy of Sciences.

What is the meaning of "conceive" in this context? Does it mean to think about it?

Comment: Just google **conceive**. -- **to imagine**. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/conceive

Comment: @RonaldSole Is it right to imagine a question?

Comment: Yes, why not? Take a teacher: he/she imagines questions and their possible answers before including the questions in a test. Alternatively, "conceive of" can also be deemed to be synonymous with "think of".

Comment: If he found it difficult to "think about" the question, it's possible the question would be there, well formed, created in his mind, and he merely couldn't think about it.   This is something more;  there's something wrong with the state of being of the question itself.  He can't conceive of it; it's not formed, it barely exists in a real, tangible sense as an idea.